# special characters in HTML problems

Tags: html, character

Although I included the ISO-8859-1 content-type META, my website isn't displaying special characters, such as ã and ê. If I 'echo' a string from a MYSQL query, the special character is displaying properly. If I write the SAME character in plain HTML, it won't display in the same website.
Thanks in advance.

http://popguest.com.br/event/index3.php?c=48&p=3

Comment: Why don't you use `UTF-8` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a simple routine to encode all special characters to entities (&#x----; with correct hexadecimal unicode number after x)

(and switching to UTF-8 is not a bad idea)

Comment: using UTF-8 won't work either. I don't want to use hexadecimal unicode number because the website has many dynamic text (from databases, etc). I would really appreciate to make it work right away when I "print" the character

Comment: The page now declares UTF-8 and apparently *is* UTF-8 encoded and the characters are rendered OK. So presumably the “switching to UTF-8” part of the answer was applied.

Comment: if the texts come from several sources, it would be a good idea that the page and all sources use the same encoding.